# VSCode/Rubocop complaining about unconfigured cops

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I've recently updated `rubocop` for a gem I'm working on. When I open a ruby file in the project using VSCode, I get the following warning:

```
The following cops were added to RuboCop, but are not configured. Please set Enabled to either `true` or `false` in your `.rubocop.yml` file:
 - Lint/RaiseException (0.81)
 - Lint/StructNewOverride (0.81)
 - Style/HashEachMethods (0.80)
 - Style/HashTransformKeys (0.80)
 - Style/HashTransformValues (0.80)
For more information: https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/versioning/
```

Here is my `.rubocop.yml` file:

```yaml
Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 20
Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 100
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
```

When I visit the [url](https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/versioning/) in the warning it mentions adding a `NewCops` setting like so:

```yaml
Metrics/MethodLength:
  Max: 20
Layout/LineLength:
  Max: 100
AllCops:
  NewCops: enable
  Exclude:
    - 'spec/**/*'
```

However, I'm getting this new warning:

```
Warning: AllCops does not support NewCops parameter.

Supported parameters are:

  - RubyInterpreters
  - Include
  - Exclude
  - DefaultFormatter
  - DisplayCopNames
  - DisplayStyleGuide
  - StyleGuideBaseURL
  - ExtraDetails
  - StyleGuideCopsOnly
  - EnabledByDefault
  - DisabledByDefault
  - UseCache
  - MaxFilesInCache
  - CacheRootDirectory
  - AllowSymlinksInCacheRootDirectory
  - TargetRubyVersion
The following cops were added to RuboCop, but are not configured. Please set Enabled to either `true` or `false` in your `.rubocop.yml` file:
 - Lint/RaiseException (0.81)
 - Lint/StructNewOverride (0.81)
 - Style/HashEachMethods (0.80)
 - Style/HashTransformKeys (0.80)
 - Style/HashTransformValues (0.80)
For more information: https://docs.rubocop.org/en/latest/versioning/
```

The warning instructs me to enable each of these new cops individually but the docs seem to have an easier solution that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue here. The `NewCops` parameter inside `AllCops` is not recognized so there is only one way to do it which is by disabling or enabling each cop alone like so:

```
Lint/RaiseException:
  Enabled: false
Lint/StructNewOverride:
  Enabled: false
Style/HashEachMethods:
  Enabled: false
Style/HashTransformKeys:
  Enabled: false
Style/HashTransformValues:
  Enabled: false
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using VS code ruby-rubocop version here is a simple fix for you ->

Configure extension settings -> Select Supress Rubocop Warnings , it is helpful if you share rubocop.yml file in the repository.

[image]

Comment: Very useful. Someone has suggested an edit for your post because the image is not embedded in the answer. I suggest adding it with the WYSIWYG editor. I can do it for you but figured you'd rather edit your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `NewCops` parameter is not supported yet. However, it will be supported in the next release of Rubocop. Next to this parameter, you will also be able to use `--enable-pending-cops` and `--disable-pending-cops` command-line options.

For the moment EL Zakariae's solution is the only way to remove this warning.

You can find the corresponding pull request [here](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/7856).

Comment: Hi Simon, thx for your first contribution! Awesome. I think it would be great if you could add version numbers instead of saying "not yet" / "will be in the future" this way the answer will be more helpful in the future :-)